# PhantomJS load blank page and run script

Tags: phantomjs

Is it possible to load a blank page and execute some javascript on the page?  If so, how?  Examples would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

PhantomJS needs a DOM and that won't be present on an empty file. You need to create at least this structure for your page to execute `JavaScript` on the page:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- JavaScript goes here !-->
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I was actually looking for something like this:

```
 var page = require('webpage').create();
 page.open('about:blank', function(status) {
    page.evaluate(function() {
       //My script here.         
    });
    phantom.exit();
});
```

Comment: This should work since it loads a blank page with the basic HTML structure.

Answer (score 1):

Try page.setContent

http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/set-content.html

```
var webPage = require('webpage');
var page = webPage.create();
var expectedContent = '<html><body><div>' + yourScript + '</div></body></html>';
var expectedLocation = 'http://www.phantomjs.org/';
page.setContent(expectedContent, expectedLocation, function(status) {
   if(status === success) {
       page.evaluate();
   } else {
       //do something
   }
});
```